# Sum of fractional parts of linear and logarithmic functions

Tags: calculus, analysis, analytic-number-theory

Fix real numbers $\alpha, \beta \geq 0$ with $\alpha$ irrational, and let $N$ be a positive integer. For $x \in \mathbb{R}$, let $\{x\} := x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ denote the fractional part of $x$. Are there any estimates known for the following sums
\begin{equation}
S_1 := \sum_{n=1}^N \left(\{\alpha n + \beta\} - \dfrac{1}{2}\right)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
S_2 := \sum_{n=1}^N \left(\{\log(\alpha n + \beta)\} - \dfrac{1}{2}\right).
\end{equation}
Is it true that $S_1 = o(N)$ and $S_2 = o(N)$ as well? What are methods that may be useful for estimating such sums? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would expect $S_1=\frac{N}{2}+o(N)$, though.  It may be the case that $S_2=\frac{N}{2}+o(N)$ as well.

Comment: Can your guess be proven?

Comment: Well, a heuristic argument is that $\big\{\alpha n +\beta\big\}$ and $\big\{\log(\alpha n+\beta)\big\}$ are (probably) uniformly distributed on $[0,1)$.  If this is true, then we may even have the estimate $\frac{N}{2}+\mathcal{O}\big(\sqrt{N}\big)$ for both $S_1$ and $S_2$.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. But not true until proven :)

Comment: Have fixed the post now

Comment: After a trial with $\alpha=\sqrt{2}$ and $\beta=0$, $\big\{\log(\alpha n+\beta)\big\}$ does not seem uniformly random.  But it may still hold that, now with the new definitiosn, $S_2=o(N)$ (although I wouldn't expect $S_2=\mathcal{O}\big(\sqrt{N}\big)$ anymore).  I'm too tired to think about $S_1$ now, but it should not be difficult to show $S_1=\mathcal{O}\big(\sqrt{N}\big)$.

Comment: Regarding $S_2$, since the $\log$ function grows slowly, I feel that $\Delta = S_2(\beta_1) - S_2(\beta_2)$ should be small for any real numbers $\beta_1, \beta_2 \in [0,1]$